# Angularfire2.5 Real Time Database with angular material autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angularfire2

I am trying to use the angular material autocomplete input field with angularfire2 v5.

I have some difficulties adapting the shown example: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples to a firebase list.

It seems that the functions used in the example can't work with an observable input:

The following code :

```js
  // FROM COMPOSERS.SERVICE.TS

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
     this.membersRef = db.list('/members');
     this.members = this.membersRef.valueChanges();
    }

    getFilteredMembersList() { 
     return this.membersRef.snapshotChanges()
      .startWith(null)
      .map(member => member ? this.filerMembers(member) : this.members.slice());
    }

    filerMembers(member) {
      return this.members.filter(member =>
        member.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(member.firstname.toLowerCase()) === 0);
    }
   
   
   // FROM COMPOSER-LIST.COMPONENT.TS
        
 memberCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

    ngOnInit() {
     this.filteredMembers = this.memberService.getFilteredMembersList();
    }
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Search Member" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="memberCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let member of filteredMembers | async" 
     [value]="member.firstname">
      <span>{{ member.firstname }} {{ member.lastname }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

brings me this error :

Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Observable[]>'.

I can't find the way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `filterMembers` we are dealing with an subscription, you cannot use `filter` on an subscription. We need to include `map`, and also flatten the data in the `valueChanges` for example with `switchMap` instead of using `map`:

```ts
this.filteredMembers = this.memberCtrl.valueChanges
  .startWith(null)
  .switchMap(val => {
    return this.filterMembers(val || '')
  })
```

and below we need as mentioned use `map`, since `filter` cannot be applied to an supscription directly.

```ts
filterMembers(val: string) {
  return this.members
    .map(response => response.filter(option => { 
      return option.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }));
}
```

Your template is correct as it sits! :)

Here's a DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/enR5EijpNPHNtTTquFfu?p=preview

Comment: that is a big help thanks a lot AJT_82 for your message I learned a lot!

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :) :)