# Unable to map autocomplete valueChanges with Cloud Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, angular5, mat-autocomplete

I am using [material autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) in a project but unlike their example, I'm pulling from cloud firestore database (beta). 
I previously set up a service to handle retrieving the data from [json server](http://my-json-server.typicode.com/mduve/services/branches) and this worked fine.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.branches = this.branchService.get_branches();
      ...
  }
```

Since moving to the firebase I'm **successfully able to display my data** but **typeahead functionality is not working** as expected.

I've tried using both valueChanges() and snapshotChanges() but neither appears to make a difference and I don't know why.

component.ts file:

```
branches: any = [];
branchCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
filteredBranches: Observable<any[]>;

branchCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Branch>;
branch$: Observable<Branch[]>;

constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) {

}

ngOnInit() {

  this.branchCol = this.afs.collection('branches');
  //this.branch$ = this.branchCol.valueChanges();
  this.branch$ = this.branchCol.snapshotChanges().map(actions => { return actions.map(action => { const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Branch; const id = action.payload.doc.id; return { id, ...data }; }); });

  this.branches = this.branch$;


  this.filteredBranches = this.branchCtrl.valueChanges
    .startWith(null)
    //.map(b => b && typeof b === 'object' ? b.name : b)
    .switchMap(val => {
      return this.filterBranches(val || '')
    });
}

displayFn(b): string {
  return b ? b.name : b;
}
filterBranches(val: string) {
  return this.branches
    .map(response => response.filter(option => {
      return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }));
}

getBranch(value){
  console.log('branch selected');
}
```

My assumption is filteredBranches is not able to map the value changes correctly due to collection/document data structure of firebase. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You say "but filter functionality is not working as expected" can you elaborate the problem you're seeing and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, I am able to retrieve data from the database but the filter, or typeahead behavior, doesn't work. In my ngOnInit, I'm assigning this.branches to this.branch$ (an observable). I don't know if this is the culprit or can I just edit filterBranches to handle the data differently?  


This a similar post but in his/her example, they are using real time database:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094045/angularfire2-5-real-time-database-with-angular-material-autocomplete